# Aws Enforce MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

Is there a way to prevent a user to login into aws and display an MFA enabling

User->login ( prevented because the MFA is disabled ) -> enable MFA -> login successfully

Thank you

I tried creating a policy to deny actions if a user has an mfa disabled ( that can solve the issue but i want to push the user toward enabling mfa so he can login to his account)

Comment: You will need to allow the user to log in and go to the MFA setup screen and do that MFA setup before they can the *re*login with MFA to get MFA protected access.